# Is there any way to smoothly animate the colour of text on hover?

Tags: javascript, css

The design I'm working with includes a button hover that fills in the button with colour. Over this is text that on initial state is the same colour as the fill. As the fill proceeds, the colour of the text changes to a contrasting colour, but smoothly. Here is a still of the video the designer gave me that illustrates the issue:

[image]

You can see on the letter 'a' that it is two different colours. So I can't change the colour of the text letter-by-letter.

Is there any method (JS/Jquery/whatever/CSS), to achieve this? I'm thinking not, but maybe there is some way of animating a sharp gradient across the text? I don't know.

Comment: You can't animate CSS gradients...

Comment: afaik, you can't hit text letters, other than the first for some things.

Comment: Just found this: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/ So I might try something along this line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually did something similar for another question a while ago.

This can be achieved with [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). I also slowed the timing down to `5s` so that you can clearly see how it works. Change that to `0.25s` or whatever meets your needs when in use.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 3px solid #f16251;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transform-origin:0 0 ;
  transform:translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 5s;
  z-index: 3;
}
a:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

a:after{
  content: '';
  display:block;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #f16251;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">WoOoOoOoT</a>
```

Comment: @Snowmonkey thank you very much, it was a real pain to figure out. Especially because the other OP asked for it to be done without additional html markup.

Comment: Nice! But looks like it might be iffy on IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode Will test it out though :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, this is the bleeding edge, I wouldn't expect it to work without any issues cross-browser. http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Comment: Wow, this is pretty sweet, Chrome, Firefox and Safari support: http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode